# Error when trying to integrate parse into Android app error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am attempting to recreate a running app I made in iOS for Android to release together I am attempting to integrate parse into the Android app and receive the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

could someone assist as to what this could mean and how can I go about fixing it?

I downloaded the latest parse SDK and placed in the dependencies in the build.gradle.

Comment: Hey, have you solved this problem? I get the same error, but can not find solution.

Comment: yes the solution below worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `clean` and rebuild your project and if the problem still persist, Try adding `multiDexEnabled true` to your app `build.gradle` file.

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: now I get the error:    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bolts/AppLink$Target.class

Comment: Try to compile with latest version of `multidex`. Add this into gradle `depedencies` it is `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`