# Gradle unable to build app with Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-gradle-plugin

Hello everyone i am new to parse and i am trying to connect my android app to parse but it is showing error below

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 2

my gradle file is shown below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.thakur.space"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
}
```

plz help me on this how to fix this..

Comment: That error has nothing to do with "connecting" to parse. Your app just couldn't build. It's a Gradle error, and I doubt that is Parses fault

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080160/error-when-trying-to-integrate-parse-into-android-app-error-errorexecution-fai

Answer (score 2):

### Whats your logcat throws

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 2

The Android plugin for Gradle available in Android SDK Build Tools
 21.1 and higher supports multidex as part of your build configuration. Make sure you update the Android SDK Build Tools tools and the Android
 Support Repository to the latest version using the SDK Manager before
 attempting to configure your app for multidex.

Setting up your app development project to use a multidex configuration requires that you make a few modifications to your app development project.

In particular you need to perform the following steps:

1. **Change your Gradle build configuration to enable multidex**
2. **Modify your manifest to reference the MultiDexApplication class**

*Modify your app Gradle build file configuration to include the support library and enable multidex output .*

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    // Add yours
}
```

Then  ***clean and rebuild Your Project With Sync*** .

Read

> http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: I have enable multidexEnabled true i gradle butnow it is showing error given below:-

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/AbstractQueryController$1.class

Comment: Actually this problem appears when version conflicts with gradle system or same library called in your build section . need to debug on it

Comment: I mailed u required files plz take a look on that....and let me know thw solution

Comment: Okay .I will . Keep Patients .